# While installing DATA MIGRATION TOOL, this error shows

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, migration

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

```
 The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: all  
  ow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https:// wrapper is disabled in th  
  e server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0                                  
  failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found) 'enter code here'
```

Can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `php_value allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini`

```
  php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

Usually `php.ini` located in  `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: Would that not want to be `allow_url_fopen = On` if in `php.ini` and `php_value allow_url_fopen On` if in a `.htaccess` file (which presumably won't help with a composer issue).